# Select multiple joined tables into multiple variables in SQL queries or LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, select, join

```
SELECT O.*, U.*, C.*, P.*, S.* 
INTO OV, Usuarios, Clientes, Proposta, Status 
FROM[dbo].[TB_OV] O 
INNER JOIN dbo.TB_Usuarios U on U.id = O.userinsert 
INNER JOIN dbo.TB_Clientes C on C.id = O.ENDFAT 
INNER JOIN dbo.TB_Status S on S.id = O.status 
LEFT JOIN TB_Proposta P on P.id = O.ID_PROP 
WHERE O.status = 214 ORDER BY O.DTSOL, O.DtdeFaturamento
```

I am developing a web system in C# and one of the queries that I am trying to do is this one...
I want to know what is the correct syntax to do that or something like this.

What I need to know exactly is how to select this five tables into five different variables like an object to each one that I can cast later in C# to turn into object typed.

Otherwise, I've tried to do it with LINQ to SQL from C# and I still did not get any results from queries in LINQ to SQL to these tables.

Lambda:

```
var query = db.TB_OV
    .Join(db.TB_Usuarios, OV => OV.USERINSERT, U => U.ID, (OV, U) => new { OV, U })
    .Join(db.TB_Clientes, Z => Z.OV.ENDFAT, CL => CL.ID, (Z, CL) => new { Z, CL })
    .Join(db.TB_Status, Z => Z.Z.OV.STATUS, ST => ST.ID, (Z, ST) => new { Z, ST })
    .Join(db.TB_Proposta, Z => Z.Z.Z.OV.ID_PROP, P => P.ID, (Z, P) => new { Z, P })
    .Where(Z => Z.Z.Z.Z.OV.STATUS == 214)
    .Select(Z => new OperacoesListaSolFaturamento
    {
        OV = Z.Z.Z.Z.OV,
        Usuarios = Z.Z.Z.Z.U,
        Clientes = Z.Z.Z.CL,
        Status = Z.Z.ST,
        Proposta = Z.P
    });
```

Fluent:

```
var query = from O in db.TB_OV
            join U in db.TB_Usuarios on O.USERINSERT equals U.ID
            join C in db.TB_Clientes on O.ENDFAT equals C.ID
            join S in db.TB_Status on O.STATUS equals S.ID
            join P in db.TB_Proposta on O.ID_PROP equals P.ID
            where O.STATUS == 214
            select new OperacoesListaSolFaturamento
            {
                OV = O,
                Usuarios = U,
                Clientes = C,
                Status = S,
                Proposta = P
            };
```

Is there any way to do that? Either by LINQ or SQL queries.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, can you clarify it by adding some samples and the desired outcome?

Comment: Well, sorry for that, i will try to simplify

Comment: Try to understand now and tell me if you realized it

Comment: This doesn't work the way you think it does. 1. The * symbol is replaced with all of the actual columns.  2. The Into clause doesn't support multiple target tables.

Comment: So how can i do this in any other way? With SQL Query or LINQ

Comment: `INTO` is a shortcut syntax for creating tables on the database side (and it's probably not the best idea to do it that way). It has nothing to do with C# and populating object collections.

Comment: @PedroLopes What SQL are you using that supports `INTO` like that? Alternatively can you post a valid SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

For translating SQL to LINQ query comprehension:

1. Translate `FROM` subselects as separately declared variables.
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, translating monadic and aggregate operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, `MIN`, `MAX` etc) into functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new {` ... `}`) for multiple columns.
5. `LEFT JOIN` is simulated by using `into` *joinvariable* and doing another from `from` the *joinvariable* followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.
6. Replace `COALESCE` with the conditional operator (`?:`)and a `null` test.
7. Translate `IN` to `.Contains()` and `NOT IN` to `!`...`Contains()`.
8. Translate *x* `BETWEEN` *low* `AND` *high* to *low* `<=` *x* `&&` *x* `<=` *high*.
9. `SELECT *` must be replaced with select range_variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
10. `SELECT` fields must be replaced with `select new {` ... `}` creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.
11. Proper `FULL OUTER JOIN` must be handled with an extension method.

So the main problem with your fluent query is you didn't translate the `LEFT JOIN` properly:

```
var query = from O in db.TB_OV
            where O.STATUS == 214
            join U in db.TB_Usuarios on O.USERINSERT equals U.ID
            join C in db.TB_Clientes on O.ENDFAT equals C.ID
            join S in db.TB_Status on O.STATUS equals S.ID
            join P in db.TB_Proposta on O.ID_PROP equals P.ID into Pj
            from P in Pj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            orderby O.DTSOL, O.DtdeFaturamento
            select new OperacoesListaSolFaturamento
            {
                OV = O,
                Usuarios = U,
                Clientes = C,
                Status = S,
                Proposta = P
            };
```